# Can a Microsoft account be used for file permissions

Tags: windows, file-permissions, microsoft-account

If I use my_MicrosoftAccount@hotmail.com on two computers (A and B), can I use it for file-permissions between different machines in my network?

ie Can I access files that my_MicrosoftAccount@hotmail.com (Not an account connected to A) has access to on B if I am logged on as my_MicrosoftAccount@hotmail.com on A?

What if the files are on an external drive, and I move the drive between 2 computers?

Comment: Yes; Of course you can because the local account that is linked to those accounts are 100% unique.

Comment: You mean A\my_MicrosoftAccount@hotmail and B\my_MicrosoftAccount@hotmail are 2 unique accounts? (I have tried to make my question clearer)

Comment: Yes;  You have two machines.  Even if the local account were both called A, they would be unique users, even if they were linked to the same Microsoft Account.  This is standard file sharing on Windows by the way.